# ASP.NET - Running PowerShell script using pass-through authentication (Windows Authentication)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, powershell, windows-authentication

I'm creating MVC3-based intranet application in ASP.NET. The application is really simple:
- asking for input (username)
- running PowerShell script using provided username (fetching some data from remote database)
- piping script output to HTML file
- redirecting to created HTML file.

For security reasons, I'm using Windows Authentication with access only for specified groups of users. This works great for the application itself - I can see current username in the corner, not specified users do not have access.

The problem is PS script itself. It didn't seem to work with user's credentials, so I added `whoami` line to the script and got result: `iis apppool\asp.net v4.0`.

This is the code I'm using to run PS script:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.Commands.AddScript(@"CommandHere");
ps.Invoke();
```

How can I run it using current user's credentials?

Comment: Why not just make your script auth through windows. It will use the windows credentials. Add validation in your asp.net form, which will only allow whomever to have access.

<ref>
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dvespa/archive/2010/02/22/how-to-use-windows-authentication-with-the-pscredential-class.aspx

Comment: I'm quite new to PowerShell and ASP.NET. Could you give me some more details how to use it in my code?